# ui-select without ng-repeat

Tags: ui-select, angular-ui-select

I need to add two choices to `ui-select`, and instead of using repeat and an array I think the code is clearer if they are marked up inside `<ui-select-choices>` (see example below). But it doesn't work, any ideas if this is somehow possible?

```
     <ui-select ng-model="formula.value">
         <ui-select-match>
            <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
         </ui-select-match>
         <ui-select-choices>
             <span>AND</span>
             <span>OR</span>
         </ui-select-choices>
     </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as `ui-select-choices` *requires* the `repeat` attribute, as seen on line 21 in [the source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/uiSelectChoicesDirective.js). Instead, the following markup works and doesn't sacrifice readability, IMO:

```
<ui-select ng-model="formula.value" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match>{{ $select.selected }}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="choice in ['AND', 'OR']">
    <span>{{ choice }}</span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FFTu9x?p=preview)